# queries to a University database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to write the following queries to the following database:

[image: University Database]
The queries are:

1. For each department, find the maximum salary of instructors in that department. You may assume that every department has at least one instructor.
2. Find the lowest, across all departments, of the per-department maximum salary computed by the preceding query.

I managed to do the first one, but I am stuck on the second one. What I tried to do is get the result from the first query and wrtie a subquery to get me the result for the second question.

here is my code:

```
    SELECT DEPT_NAME, MIN(SALARY)
    FROM instructor
    WHERE DEPT_NAME IN
   (SELECT DEPT_NAME, MAX(SALARY)
    FROM instructor
    GROUP BY DEPT_NAME);
```

I tried different variations but I cant get it to work.

Comment: This looks like homework, what have you tried?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Please show in your question that you have actually _tried_ to solve the problem and come up with a question to a _specific_ problem you have.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site where you can ask questions and get answers about problems you're having with software you've written, but it is not a "do my homework for me" site. When you ask a question you should include the code you've written and the specific errors you're getting or the results your program produces and an explanation of the results you expected. Without that there's really not much we can do to help you. Please edit your question to show what you've done and tell us what problems the code has. Again, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your first query is:

```
SELECT   DEPT_NAME,
         MAX(SALARY) AS MAX_DEPT_SALARY
FROM     instructor
GROUP BY DEPT_NAME
```

Then you can just use the rows from this as your sub-query to select from:

```
SELECT <something>
FROM   (
         SELECT   DEPT_NAME,
                  MAX(SALARY) AS MAX_DEPT_SALARY
         FROM     instructor
         GROUP BY DEPT_NAME
       )
```

Then you will need to work out what the `<something>` is that you will need to find. Well the question gives you the answer:

> Find the lowest, across all departments, of the per-department maximum salary computed by the preceding query.

I'll leave it to you to complete finding the minimum of those department's maximum salaries that you've already found.

Comment: Upvote for addressing the foundational issue - a basic structure for solving a multi-part problem; and then letting him solve the concrete problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
 SELECT DEPARTMENT, MAX(SALARY)
   FROM <tablename>
  GROUP BY DEPARTMENT;
```